# How do I connect Form.io to an external api to get data then post dynamically to form?

Tags: reactjs, formio

I am trying to use Form.io as a part of a project, but am not able to get and display data from an external API. The API requires an apiToken to communicate with it, but I cannot figure out how to achieve that from the form.io portal.

There is not much documentation and very few examples on how to make these connections, and so I would like some advice or direction.

Using this link, https://formio.github.io/formio.js/app/builder, using a select component, how do I make the connection to an external datasource (API). (Example API dataset: http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees)

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**you need in the first time**

`npm install react-formio --save`

**then import it**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Form} from 'react-formio';
```

**then...**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Form src="yourLinkHere" onSubmit={console.log} />
  , document.getElementById('example')
);
```

And if you like, follow this [LINK : Click Here](https://github.com/formio/react-formio)

***GoodLuck bro .***

Comment: I have the ability to bring in the form into my react application, but the issue is that I need to be able to populate selection criteria with data gotten from a restAPI.

Comment: The idea you need has not yet been received

Comment: I have downloaded the source code from the link but there is no start script in package.json file. So how can i run this application

Comment: I hope you add the specific codes to your code, don't download the source code.